# Statistics - How to create data sample of specific distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

Lets say I want to create a data of 10K samples, that have a median of X, a mean of Y and I want to control where the IQR will be. How can I achieve this using `Scipy` and `Numpy` libraries?

Let the distribution be normal, I tried using `Scipy.stats`:

```
r = stats.norm.rvs(size=10000,loc=4600)
```

This gives me 10K samples, with a mean of 4600, but I don't understand how can I control the median and the IQR.

**EDIT:**

To be more clear, I've been assigned to create two data samples that follow these rules: one with X samples > second with Y, both have the same median of M, x IQR is smaller than y IQR, x mean is m1 and y mean is m2, m1 is bigger than m2. The distribution was not mentioned.

Comment: What distribution do you want (obviously not normal, as the IQRs would be a function of mean and std), or at least how are your IQRs defined?  Some explanation of what inputs you have and what outputs you want would be useful

Comment: I've been assigned to create two data samples that follow these rules: one with X samples > second with Y, both have the same median, x IQR is smaller than y IQR, x mean is larger than y mean. The distribution was not mentioned(but the questions suggests two fit the discription). Hope the requirements are clear.. @DanielF

Comment: That's not clear at all, actually.  In the original question you mentioned finding a distribution with a mean X and a median Y, and an IQR.  Without knowing which distribution you want, the problem is underdetermined.  You probably want to ask [stats.se] for what you want to implement on the statistical side before you ask us to try to implement

Comment: Because if I'll be able to do that, I'll be able to create the two distributions. My question is with which distribution is it possible and how, regardless of this specific question, because I have other questions involving different distributions as well.. @DanielF

Comment: [scipy.stats documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html)